# AddSubview adding multiple Subviews

Tags: swift, parent-child, subview

I have created a bottom sheet and within the bottom sheet I have added a button to call another subview. The code for calling this second subview is:

```
func addSettings() {

    let settingsVC = SettingsViewController()

    if !settingsVC.view.isDescendant(of: self.view) {

        self.addChildViewController(settingsVC)
        self.view.addSubview(settingsVC.view)
        settingsVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        // 3- Adjust bottomSheet frame and initial position.
        let height = view.frame.height
        let width  = view.frame.width
        settingsVC.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:self.view.frame.maxY, width: width, height: height)

    } else {
        // 2- Add bottomSheetVC as a child view
        settingsVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

    }
}
```

Whenever I call this function it adds another subview. If I press the button again and call this function again another SettingsViewController is added and this repeats every time I click the button.

Ideally I would like for this function to check if the SettingsViewController subview already exists and if it does then don't add another subview.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are creating a new `SettingsViewController()` whenever you call `addSettings`. You should define `settingsVC` as a class property and use it like `self.settingsVC`.

Comment: @ozgur i do have it as a separate class. just thorught it would be too much code to put in here. The issue is within this function. I'm trying to figure out how to check if the subview is already added every time this function is called.

Comment: Try something like this print(self.view.subviews.contains(where: { $0 is UIButton }))